# Leaflet pass geoJson parameter to onEachFeature method

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I created geoJson object as below:

```
var geoJson= L.geoJson(groupingLevelType.type, {
                style: style,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                });

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
                layer.on({
                    mouseover: highlightFeature,
                    mouseout: resetHighlight
                });

    function resetHighlight(e) {
                geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
            }
```

In `resetHighlight` method I want to reset style of `geoJson`.How I can pass `geoJson` as parameter to `onEachFeature` method.Or there there is any other way separate `onEachFeature` from creation of `geoJson` to be able to reset style?

Answer (score 1):

It is another solution where you get the GeoJSON reference from the event

```
const resetHighlight = e => {
const foo = e.sourceTarget._eventParents;
foo[Object.keys(foo)[0]].resetStyle(e.target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JavaScript scoping, you should be able to use your `geoJson` variable within your `onEachFeature` function without the need to "pass [it] as parameter".

Note that you may have a typo: `geojson.resetStyle(e.target);` should be `geoJson…` (note the capital `J`) to match your variable name.

Once this typo is corrected, your code looks to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/180/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.This is true but in my case it is not solve my problem.I shared the solution I have found.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution like that for my problem,I separated code in different classes and I want to a code more readable.So I do not want to rely on scope of javascript,I set layer style again in `resetHighlight` method:

```
function resetHighlight(e) {
   var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
            color: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });
}
```

and in this way I do not have to pass geoJson as parameter.
Hope this helps another user.